# Collapsing Toolbar Layout with PDF Viewer

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

I am using Collapsing Toolbar Layout with PDF Viewer lib by barteksc. 
The problem is when i scroll up PDF viewer scrolling is not working. 
When i start scrolling up Collapsing Toolbar Layout works fine but under that PDF Viewer not scroll.
I try every possible solution but no success, here is my code ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    tools:context=".activity.showArticle">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="Deprission">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/depression"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/back"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@mipmap/back_icon" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
            android:id="@+id/pdfView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/heart_filled"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/appColor"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Hey did you find any solution?